# How can i convert 31 colums (refering to the days of month) into a single datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, multiple-columns

I have this:

**Febuary_Sells**

(31 columns refering to the days of month)

```
  Store | Product | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  ...  | 31 |
Store 1 | Iphone  | 0 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |  ...  | 0  |  
Store 1 | 4k TV   | 1 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 0 |  ...  | 0  |
```

And i want to have something like this:

```
  Store | Product |    Date    | Quantity |
Store 1 | Iphone  | 01/02/2022 |     0    |  
Store 1 | 4k TV   | 01/02/2022 |     1    |  
Store 1 | Iphone  | 02/02/2022 |     3    |  
Store 1 | 4k TV   | 02/02/2022 |     4    |
```

I just want to get rid of the 31 columns and transform it into a datetime column (also keep the quantity selled of each item)

I really don't know how can i solve this problem...

For some reason, i can't put images on my question

Comment: Have a look at [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Comment: df.melt(["Store", "Product"], var_name="Date", value_name="Quantity").assign(Date=lambda fr: fr.Date.map(lambda day: pd.Timestamp(year=2022, month=2, day=int(day))))

Comment: day is out of range for month

Comment: It seems your dataframe has columns for 31 days, though February only has 28 days. I assume this causes the error. Double-check that the last three columns only contain `0` and drop them before applying the `pd.melt` command.